# How to construct a Topology from an arbitrary collection and in which condition?

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose we are given any arbitrary collection of sets.
>
> How do get a largest topology from the above arbitrary collection?

How to construct a Topology from this collection and in which condition ?

I don't have any answer to me.

Any help or idea is appreciated.

Comment: Define "construct". What exactly are you looking for? Because you can always take discrete topology and say "I'm done".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities.

I'm going to assume you have a set $U$ whose elements are all subsets of one "big" set $A$. (For instance: you might have a set of intervals, all of which are subsets of $[0, 1]$.)

You want to find a set $U'$ such that

(1) $U \subset U'$

(2) $U'$ is a topology on $A$.

Here's one answer: let $U'$ be the power set of $A$, i.e., let $U'$ contain *all* subsets of $A$. Then the thing you get is called the "discrete" topology on $A$.

Here's a second answer: you know that a topology must contain $\emptyset$ and $A$, so let $U_1 = U \cup \{ \emptyset, A \}$. Now $U_1$ is *almost* a topology, but it doesn't necessarily contain arbitrary unions of elements, or finite intersections of elements. So

- Let $V_1 = U_1 \cup \{ \cup_{x \in X} x \mid x \in \Bbb P(U_1) \}$. That's hard to read, but the second set says "let $x$ be any element of the power set of $U_1$, i.e., any collection of subsets of $U_1$. Take the union of these things. *THAT* is one of the elements of the new set. So $V_1$ now contains arbitrary unions, and $U_1 \subset V_1$.
- Let $U_2 = V_1 \cup \{ \cap_{x \in X} x \mid x \in Bbb P'(V_1) \}$, where $\Bbb P'$ denotes the "finite power set" of a set -- the collection of all *finite* subsets of the set. So $W_1$ contains arbitrary finite intersections of elements of $V_1$.

Now repeat the process, forming $V_2$ from $U_2$, and so on. THe result is a sequence of sets
$$
U \subset U_1 \subset V_1 \subset U_2 \subset V_2 \subset ...
$$
all of which are subsets of $\Bbb P(A)$. Let

$$
H = \cup_{i=1}^\infty U_i.
$$

Then I claim that $H$ is a topology. It certainly contains the empty set and $A$. What about finite intersections? If you have a finite collection $B_1, \ldots, B_k$ of elements of $H$, then there's some $N$ so large that all the $B_i$ lie in $U_N$. But then they all lie in $V_N$ as well, so their intersection lies in $U_{N+1}$, hence in $H$.

The argument for arbitrary unions is ... probably messier. Or maybe it's completely straightforward. I think it's completely straightforward. Yep...it is. \

N.B.: Kavi Rama Murthy's answer suggests that once you compute $U_2$, you're done, i.e., after that, my process adds no new elements to the topology. That's probably right, but I can't verify it yet, because I haven't had any coffee yet this morning. :)

---

Anyhow, the construction above constructs the *smallest* topology on $A$ that contains $U$. So my two answers are at the extremes: one constructs the largest topology on $A$ that contains $U$, the other constructs the smallest. There are often many intermediate possibilities as well.

Comment: excellent answer and many thing to learn in one answer

Comment: I needed the largest topology actually and you answered both. just excellent

Answer (score 4):

First take all possible finite intersections of those sets together with the empty set and then take arbitrary unions of the new sets you have obtained. You get  a topology and this topology is the smallest topology containing the given sets. You can read about base and sub-base in  any book on topology for more information. [An empty intersection  is defined as the whole space].

Comment: Technically you also have to add the empty set and whole space.

Comment: @freakish Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The empty set comes in itself as empty union.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, excellent answer

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, how to get a largest topolgy from an arbitrary collection ?

Comment: The largest topology containing the given collections is simply the power set.